# Why is SRWLock undefined?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use SRWLock with C++ project Visual Studio 2012 (Windows 7) targeting 32-bit Windows only and SRWLock is better then CriticalSections in my case.
As i've searched, i should include WinBase.h and use std namespace. But SRWLock is still undefined. Couldn't find anything useful on Google. What i'm missing? I appreciate any clues.
Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
using namespace std;
SRWLock gLock; // here is the problem
```

Comment: Dunno what documentation told you `winbase.h` has this. [Read the **real** documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244843.aspx). If you're using that C++ .NET class, that's where to find it. If you're using the core winapi, [that documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx).  Judging by the looks of it, you wanted to use the former, but included files for the latter.

Comment: WhozCraig, thanks. One of the links pointed out a solution. You can actually rephrase my answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: I found about WinBase.h in "Windows via C\C++" book by Jeffrey Richter and Christophe Nasarre and it seems like true.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly include `winbase.h` as it is included in `windows.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where was a mistype: Should be SRWLOCK instead of SRWLock.
And you need

```
#include <windows.h>
```